# Order by nested collection filtered count

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to order by nested collection filtered count and couldn't figure out how to do it in OData.

I will use public OData API (from Microsoft) for demo to explain what I mean, no need for authorization

```
https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/
```

So we have `People` there

```
https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People
```

These `People` have `Trips`

```
https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People?$expand=Trips
```

If I want to filter `Trips` by `Name`, it's easy

```
https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People?$expand=Trips($filter=Name eq 'Trip in Beijing')
```

If I want to order `People` by `Trip` count, it's easy as well

```
https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People?$expand=Trips($count=true)&$orderby=Trips/$count desc
```

But I'm not able to order by filtered count of trips (for case when `$expand=Trips($filter=Name eq 'Trip in Beijing')`)

```
https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People?$expand=Trips($count=true;$filter=Name eq 'Trip in Beijing')&$orderby=Trips/$count desc
```

Something like `&$orderby=Trips($filter=Name eq 'Trip in Beijing')/$count desc` or `&$orderby=Trips/$count($filter=Name eq 'Trip in Beijing') desc` doesn't work (gives server error `"Could not find a property named 'Name' on type 'Trippin.Person'."`).

Version of this URL to see minimum required data

```
https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/People?$expand=Trips($top=0;$count=true;$filter=Name eq 'Trip in Beijing')&$orderby=Trips/$count desc&$select=Trips
```

---

**Update:** I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` version 7.5.7 in my project which depends on `Microsoft.OData.Core` version 7.7.3 (It's not installed explicitly). Probably if Microsoft will upgrade version of OData in its API it's going to work as well.

Comment: Hello, can you provide the error you get from the server when doing the query pls?

Comment: @Max Which one? Note that you can run all listed queries and experiment with them in your browser or Postman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** This is only supported for Microsoft.OData.Core versions >= 7.9.4 based on [this pr](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/pull/2051).

---

You should be able repeat the same filter criteria in your $orderby that you have in your $expand to get what you are looking for.

```
/odata/People?$expand=Trips($count=true;$filter=Name eq 'Paris')&$orderby=Trips/$count($filter=Name eq 'Paris') desc
```

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://localhost:5001/odata/$metadata#People(Trips())",
"value": [
    {
        "Id": "d31713ca-236b-470f-bb9e-f5bd6fac3d8e",
        "Name": "Aaron",
        "Trips@odata.count": 2,
        "Trips": [
            {
                "Id": "741656bf-f5e6-4f18-855f-ca1b3c0eb478",
                "Name": "Paris"
            },
            {
                "Id": "741656bf-f5e6-4f18-855f-ca1b3c0eb478",
                "Name": "Paris"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "34c0ac10-1c0d-4a29-89ad-386a3fea893b",
        "Name": "Bob",
        "Trips@odata.count": 1,
        "Trips": [
            {
                "Id": "1b35a96d-ca98-438a-b63c-1478ae0661cb",
                "Name": "Paris"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "192dd197-6f25-4842-bb9f-207b5df221c2",
        "Name": "Jeff",
        "Trips@odata.count": 0,
        "Trips": []
    }
  ]
}
```

For comparison, here is the same dataset without the $filter.

```
/odata/People?$expand=Trips($count=true)&$orderby=Trips/$count desc
```

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://localhost:5001/odata/$metadata#People(Trips())",
"value": [
    {
        "Id": "192dd197-6f25-4842-bb9f-207b5df221c2",
        "Name": "Jeff",
        "Trips@odata.count": 3,
        "Trips": [
            {
                "Id": "4537521c-27a6-4fa4-8bb5-fd94937abd56",
                "Name": "Cleveland"
            },
            {
                "Id": "40431cba-0d8f-470a-9647-bdd99009737a",
                "Name": "Cleveland"
            },
            {
                "Id": "1269c3e3-b5ff-4a73-8201-5388d00ea744",
                "Name": "Cleveland"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "d31713ca-236b-470f-bb9e-f5bd6fac3d8e",
        "Name": "Aaron",
        "Trips@odata.count": 2,
        "Trips": [
            {
                "Id": "741656bf-f5e6-4f18-855f-ca1b3c0eb478",
                "Name": "Paris"
            },
            {
                "Id": "741656bf-f5e6-4f18-855f-ca1b3c0eb478",
                "Name": "Paris"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "34c0ac10-1c0d-4a29-89ad-386a3fea893b",
        "Name": "Bob",
        "Trips@odata.count": 1,
        "Trips": [
            {
                "Id": "1b35a96d-ca98-438a-b63c-1478ae0661cb",
                "Name": "Paris"
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This gives me error `"Could not find a property named 'Name' on type 'Trippin.Person'."`.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't work (i.e. gives error above). You have access there. It's public API without authentication. You can even launch it from your browser. Just open this URL as a common link.

Comment: I see. Trying the same with the api in your example gives me the same result. In your final implementation are you using a specific version of OData? I was able to reliably reproduce the behavior in my answer with a local .NET 5 Web API using OData 8.0.4. I would happily share my source code.

Comment: I found this pr which makes me think this may only be supported in more recent versions. https://github.com/OData/odata.net/pull/2051/files

Comment: Here is my repo if you want to dig into this further https://github.com/tyharbert/ODataApiSandbox

Comment: Great, I was able to test it and managed to upgrade my code. NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` of version 8.0+ has huge number of breaking changes, I would even say it complete redesign of API. So I'm not planning upgrading it yet because it will need tremendous efforts to upgrade. I was able to fix it by upgrading `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` from version 7.5.7 to 7.5.12 which is the latest 7.x version at the moment. It depends on `Microsoft.OData.Core` version 7.9.0 which contains this fix.

Comment: So solution is option 1: to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData` of version 7.5.12 (or greater if it will be released) and it will implicitly use `Microsoft.OData.Core` version 7.9.0 (or maybe greater) or option 2: explicitly install `Microsoft.OData.Core` version 7.9.0+.

Comment: I will give you bounty in the last day to get maximum possible attention (views/upvotes/comments etc) for question and answer(s). I am very grateful for your input.